# What's the most efficient way to split a sentence into words while maintaining whitespace?

Tags: php, string, split

Let's say I have a "sentence" consisting of "words" and spaces such as:

```
'  foo bar    foobar   '
```

Specifically a word is any set of characters not including a space. There is one or more spaces between each word. The leading and trailing spaces are optional.

I'd like the simplest way to separate the words *and* spaces into a collection such as:

```
[ '  ', 'foo', ' ', 'bar, '    ', 'foobar', '   ']
```

I tried using `explode()` with the space character as the separator, but of course, the results did not include the spaces. I tried `preg_match()` without success, but that may be because I couldn't find the right regular expression.

I could process the sentence character by character, but I feel like there should be an easier way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using the following which worked for me:

```
$s = '  foo bar    foobar   ';

preg_match_all('/\s+|\w+/', $s, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

giving out spaces and words in an array of array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>   
            [1] => foo
            [2] =>  
            [3] => bar
            [4] =>     
            [5] => foobar
            [6] =>    
        )

)
```

But is this the most efficient way? I will leave that to you to judge :)

Comment: maybe check if (($key % 2) != 0) ? I think that would give all the odds. Instead of needing to do some crazy logic.

Comment: Thanks, this did the job.